# How to load data from external JSON file in Webix tree with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, webix

How to load the data from an external JSON file in Webix tree component. I have tried with $http method of AngularJS but Webix components are not setting the response of http service as their data parameter.

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: Yes, Actually I have resolved the issue. I wanted to fetch the data in Webix Tree from and External JSON file. So, I used the webix Parse method to attach data for the Webix Tree.